# Mockito verify number of invocations in spring boot test

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito

I'm trying to verify that a mocked method (`fileSenderService.sendFile`) was called exactly 2 times. For whatever reason Mockito never fails the test, no matter what number of invocations are expected. I'm using it like this:

`verify(mockService, times(expectedNumberOfInvocations)).sendFile(any(String.class), any(byte[].class));`

No matter what value I use in the times() method, the test always passes.

The MyService looks like this:

```
@Service
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService {

    @Autowired
    private FileSenderService fileSenderService;

    public void createAndSendFiles(){
        //doSomeStuff, prepare fileNames and fileContents(byte arrays)
        //execute the sendFile twice
        fileSenderService.sendFile(aFileName, aByteArray); //void method; mocked for testing
        fileSenderService.sendFile(bFileName, bByteArray); //void method; mocked for testing
    }
```

The test class

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@SpringBootTest(classes = {Application.class, FileSenderServiceMock.class})
@ContextConfiguration
public class MyServiceTest{

    @Autowired
    private MyService myService;

    @Autowired
    FileSenderService mock;

    @Test
    public void shouldCreateAndSendFiles(){
        myService.createAndSendFiles(); //inside this method sendFile() is called twice
        verify(mock, times(999)).sendFile(any(String.class), any(byte[].class)); //THE PROBLEM - why times(999) does not fail the test?
    }
}
```

The FileSenderService and its mock:

```
@Service
public class FileSenderServiceImpl implements FileSenderService {
   @Override
    public void sendFile(String name, byte [] content) {
      //send the file
    }
}

//used for testing instead of the actual FileSenderServiceImpl 
public class FileSenderServiceMock {
    @Bean
    @Primary
    public FileSenderService getFileSenderServiceMock(){
        FileSenderServicemock = Mockito.mock(FileSenderService.class, Mockito.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS);

        doNothing().when(mock).sendFile(isA(String.class), isA(byte[].class));
        return mock;
    }
```

Comment: If you are testing MyService you shouldn't Autowire the FileSenderService but mock it (@Mock annotation) and in the test itself add the "doNothing()..." line before calling myService.createAndSendFiles()

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `@SpringBootTest` for integration test cases you don't need to define any test config classes for mocks, you can simply use [@MockBean](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/mock/mockito/MockBean.html) annotation to inject mock into test context

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class MyServiceTest{

    @Autowired
    private MyService myService;

    @MockBean
    FileSenderService fileSenderService;

    @Test
    public void shouldCreateAndSendFiles(){
    myService.createAndSendFiles(); 
    verify(fileSenderService, times(2)).sendFile(any(String.class), any(byte[].class));
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi, using MockBean does work as expected. However I'd like to have the mock in a separate file, so that it can be shared over multiple tests(mocked service in reality contains more than one method so having to type "when(mock).someMethod.thenReturn(something)" in every test class is time-consuming.

Comment: It would be really useful if you show all the code, like from which package is the "verify" method coming from, since most IDEs can't figure out imports for static method.

Comment: Most of this answer works for me; but verification is still not working when I use @MockBean. Also of note is that I'm using Junit 5, not 4 as you are doing here. Do you have any info on whether there is some specific configuration necessary for enabling verification?